# Validating date with current date using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm validating to check my passed date with current date.. but in all cases it returns false. Here is my code

```
function validateDate(date) {
       var curdate= new Date();
       curdate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
       if(new Date(date) > curdate) { 
             console.log(" greater"); 
       } else { console.log(" lesser"); };

}
```

I'm passing date as 24-10-2016

What is wrong with the code and I should not use date picker..

Comment: You should try to `console.log(curdate)`, and verify the format is what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you are passing is not the standard ISO date format. The ISO format is `YYYY-MM-DD` so you need to pass date string as `2016-10-24`

```js
var dateString = '2016-10-28'; //28th Oct 2016

validateDate(dateString);

function validateDate(date) {
       var curdate= new Date();
       curdate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
       if(new Date(date) > curdate) { 
             console.log(" greater"); 
       } else { console.log(" lesser"); };

}
```

Comment: How do you convert from 23-10-2016 to 2016-10-23 .. plz let me know.. and I'm posting this using mobile. So it's difficult for me to copy my code.

Comment: you can use like `'23-10-2016'.split('-').reverse().join('-')`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are sending the date parameter wrong

for new Date('24-10-2016') it will be an invalid date ,because it should year-month-date

change the way you send it new Date('2016-10-24')

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var firstdate = '2012-11-21';
var seconddate = '2012-11-21';
if( (new Date(firstdate).getTime() > new Date(seconddate).getTime()))
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "firstdate is greater";
}
else if( (new Date(firstdate).getTime() < new Date(seconddate).getTime()))
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "first date is not greater";
}
else if( (new Date(firstdate).getTime() == new Date(seconddate).getTime()))
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "first date is equal";
}
else
{
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "date format is not correct";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```